# Sensitive data in java heap dumps

Tags: java, encryption, passwords, heap-memory

I write software that deals with various pieces of sensitive information such as email addresses, passwords and credit card numbers.

When we're having memory trouble, it'd be nice to have the application write a heap dump.  Problem is that the heap dump may contain sensitive information in plain text if a thread happens to be working in the area... we don't really want that written to disk when we take such great pains to encrypt it everywhere else.

Are there means of dealing with this such as causing the JVM to write an encrypted dump?

Comment: wow, id be interested to see if there is a solution -- this is expensive and lame, but encrypt everything in your objects

Comment: anyone w/ a root access can get the dump and/or modify the application. So, I don't quite see a reason to encrypt anything. You can get heap dump w/ jmap of any java process.

Comment: You could sign an NDA and security agreements with anyone who might look at the heap dump... Just trying to brainstorm here.

Answer (score 4):

I've been considering handling this outside if the VM. A naive approach might be to have the jvm write the dump to an encrypted loopback device. Of course this isn't totally secure as anyone with root access can get to the mount point, but this is the sort of solution I'm expecting. I might see if I can set up a FIFO that the jvm ends up writing to. I know the filename that the vm will use, so this might work depending upon how the vm would cope with that (Later: This doesn't work.  The JVM complains with "File exists")

Using char arrays only mitigates the problem, but it's still possible that the array will contain some plain text at dump time.

Comment: I you would register, you would have got the rep onto one account.

Comment: Even if you do that doesn't the data still live as a managed heap object at some point in time.  I'm not sure where the point of diminishing returns is in risk reduction.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is not completely.  At some point you have to have the data in the clear to use it and in garbage collected VMs you can't control when objects are physically removed from memory.  The only real strategy to minimize risk is to remove all references to the unencrypted confidential data as quickly as possible. It won't guarantee that no confidential data will be written in a memory dump but if someone can do that then they can already get to the critical information.

Comment: But make sure to nuke the memory area before unreferencing it! (Thus, never store passwords in `String` objects, but use `char[]` instead.)

Comment: On a related note, I've needed to do things in the past like accept a user's password, and then pass it to a WS call, but JAXB has no way of using a byte array to pass a string value.  Does anyone know a way around that?

Comment: @Chris, "nuking" memory in java does not work. The garbage collector is free to copy the content anytime it pleases, so you would be left w/ a non-nuked object. The only you can do is using DirectCharacterBuffers, not char[], just use one big buffer and slice it since direct buffers take at least a page in memory. And to make the stuff worse, you have to clear up all the traces down incl the socket buffers. Overall it's a worthless effort.

Comment: @Chris, The jit may be good enough to optimise most forms off "nuking" into a no-op. If there was a way to hide this sort of data in programs it would have been used to create working software DRM/Copyprotection.

Answer (score 1):

Paypal has recently published a tool, to remove sensitive data from heap dumps:

https://github.com/paypal/heap-dump-tool